# Why does this hashmap have the same key twice?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, duplicates

```
// same X, Y value text.
    TextInfo currXY = new TextInfo( text );

    ArrayList<TextPosition> currTextArray = textComposition.get( currXY );
    if( currTextArray != null ){
        currTextArray.add( text ); 
    } else {
        ArrayList<TextPosition> newTextArray = new ArrayList<TextPosition>();
        newTextArray.add( text );
        if( textComposition.containsKey( currXY )){
            System.out.println( "processTextPosition : containsKEy ");
        }
        textComposition.put( currXY , newTextArray );
    }
```

A `HashMap` can't have duplicate or same key, right?

I get all entry from hashmap and put these entries into a new hashmap.

It proceed like same key.

```
lineSortingMap = new HashMap< TextInfo, ArrayList<TextPosition> > ();     
    for ( Map.Entry< TextInfo, ArrayList<TextPosition> > entry : textComposition.entrySet() ) {
        TextInfo key = (TextInfo)entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<TextPosition> arrayTextPositions = entry.getValue();
        if( lineSortingMap.containsKey( key ) ){
            System.out.println("WTFcontainsKey : " + " " + key + " " + key.getX() + " " + key.getY() );
        }
        else{
            lineSortingMap.put( key , arrayTextPositions );
        }
    }
```

result:

```
WTFcontainsKey :  analyzeSrc.TextInfo@4c5 75.307 603.85535

WTFcontainsKey :  analyzeSrc.TextInfo@4c5 71.74238 603.85535

WTFcontainsKey :  analyzeSrc.TextInfo@4c4 66.36187 612.82837

...
```

Can you explain what happens here?

Why doesn't it print "processTextPosition : containsKey"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because your Key Object doesn't override equals() and hashCode() correctly.

See the docs of [**`Object.hashCode()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and the Section [**Object as a Superclass**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) from the [**Java Tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)

Or even better: Read [**Effective Java (2nd Ed) by Joshua Bloch**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

Comment: @JoachimSauer the amazing thing is how little this is stressed in the official Sun / Oracle documentation. Both the Maps section of the Java tutorial and the HashMap JavaDocs hardly mention the importance of a consistent equals() / hashCode() implementation.

Comment: I've got the impression that much of the API documentation is written from a view influenced by formal systems ("What do you mean? The requirements for `equals()`/`hashCode()` are *clearly* documented, if you don't follow them the system is FUBAR, isn't that obvious?") as opposed to a real-world documentation ("Note, as documented in this and this location, you **must** make sure that ...").

Comment: thank you for your answer :) I do override equals() and hashCode(). but I can't understand that when first call containsKey method, it return false... next I move entries of that hashmap, but this time containsKey method return true

Comment: @HanbumBak as others have suggested, post the code of your equals() and hashCode() methods and we can see what's wrong in them.

Comment: I solve this problem. :)

when I move entries from original HashMap to lineSortingMap, I use entry object. 

like this :
TextInfo key = entry.getKey();

containsKey use getEntry method and this method use object's equals method. 

TextInfo is my custom class, but call String class's equals method. that is problem. I can't understand why but I'll fix it. thanks you :D

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to know without seeing the full code, but I'm reasonably sure that your `TextInfo` class does not correctly implement [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29). Having those two methods implemented is a prerequisite to being useful as a key in a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer :) 

I do override equals() and hashCode(). but I can't understand that when first call containsKey method, it return false... next I move entries of that hashmap, but this time containsKey method return true...

Comment: @HanbumBak: and how did you implement it? Show us the code, as that's the most likely source of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For using a object which you have created as a key in Map you should overwrite `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods. I am pretty sure that your class `TextInfo` doesn't provide the implementation for the same.